# Delete Image from cloudinary not working - Nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, cloudinary

This my implementation below. Im try to delete an image using the public id but i keep get

`{ result: 'not found' }`

Configuration:

```
 require("dotenv").config();

 cloudinary.config({
   cloud_name: process.env.CLOUD_NAME,
   api_key: process.env.CLOUD_API_KEY,
   api_secret: process.env.CLOUD_API_SECRET
 });
```

Function to delete image:

```
const deleteimage = async () = {
   return await cloudinary.uploader.destroy(
     "folder/mrobompy9ci9xawtmvcv",
     { invalidate: true, resource_type: "raw" },
     function(err, res) {
       if (err) {
         console.log(err);
         return res.status(400).json({
           ok: false,
           menssage: "Error deleting file",
           errors: err
         });
       }
       console.log(res);
     }
   );
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing `resource_type: "raw"` to `resource_type: "image"`
See [link](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/admin_api#get_resources) for additional resource_type